# GCS Connector in a non cloud environment

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I have installed GCS connector of hadoop 3 version and added the below config to core-site.xml as described in [Install.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) . The intention is to migrate data from hdfs in local cluster to cloud storage.

core-site.xml

```
fs.gs.project.id=<project-id>
fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS
google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable=true
google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=<path to key file>
```

Restarted the services .

When i try to access the bucket in the cloud to list the files , it fails .

```
 hdfs --loglevel TRACE dfs -ls gs://data-store/
```

```
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: hadoop3-2.1.4
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: gs:// = class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: file:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: viewfs:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: har:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.HarFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: http:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: https:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: hdfs:// = class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: webhdfs:// = class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: swebhdfs:// = class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.SWebHdfsFileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: s3n:// = class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem from /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-aws-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.jar
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: Looking for FS supporting gs
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: looking for configuration option fs.gs.impl
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: Filesystem gs defined in configuration option
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG fs.FileSystem: FS for gs is class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: initialize(path: gs://data-store/, config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, initSuperclass: true)
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: initializeDelegationTokenSupport(config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, path: gs://data-store/)
    20/08/17 15:44:09 TRACE gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: Failed to initialize delegation token support
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Delegation Tokens are not configured
            at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
            at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.auth.GcsDelegationTokens.init(GcsDelegationTokens.java:65)
            at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initializeDelegationTokenSupport(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:578)
            at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:555)
            at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:510)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3354)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:325)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:249)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:232)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:104)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:176)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:391)
    20/08/17 15:44:09 DEBUG gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS_ID=GHFS/hadoop3-2.1.4: configure(config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml)
```

Not sure if i missed any thing with respect to configuration. The cluster is kerberoized and there is a valid kerberos ticket (not sure if it play any relevance in this scenario.)

Is there any thing missing in the configuration ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace about `Delegation Tokens are not configured` is actually a red herring. If you read the GCS connector code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/f5fa51d46d7cbc31f68243e7fa3f284d2b460cc3/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/fs/gcs/GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java#L574-L592), you will see the connector will always try to configure delegation token support, but if you do not specify the binding through `fs.gs.delegation.token.binding` the configuration will fail, but the exception you see in the trace gets swallowed.

Now as to why your command fails, I wonder if you have a typo in your configuration file:

```
google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable-true
```

`-` instead of `=`? Or is this just a copy-paste error?

Comment: I verified the configuration and its a typo . below is the configuration entry .
 ```<property>
      <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>```
Apart from that error there is nothing much i can found out from the TRACE log .

Comment: I mean its a typo in this post.

Comment: Can you have the complete output pasted? You didn't really show what the error was other than just stating "it fails", now that we know the IllegalStateException around the delegation token configuration is not an issue.

Comment: I copied the complete tracelog here --> https://pastebin.com/embed_js/XAab7x5e

Comment: Thanks for the trace. So the `GetBucket` request on your bucket `kitchen-data-store` failed. The next thing I would do is to double check if the service account has the permission to read from that bucket.

Comment: Yep . Exactly thats the mistake . Instead of "Storage Admin" by mistake i have given "Compute Storage Admin" which screwed up the things. I  could see the relevant exception when i tried to check using `gsutil`.  Unfortunately the integration flow is not giving valid exception . @cyxxy Thanks a lot for the support.